# Power Set with 10 items maximum

Tags: c#, set, max

I kinda copy pasted and edited this code to my needs into my programm... but no i got the Problem that i only want combinations with maximum 10 members so:

1
1-2
1-2-3
1-2-3-4
.
.
.
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10

Even if i got like 20 Cards in my List. But through im not really deep into coding so i got no idea how to change it. 
My only idea was to check every result if it got more then 10 Arrays in it and if yes kick it out, but i dont think that it a very efficient way. So i wondered if you guys know a good solution and could give me some hints :)

Greets Marvin 
(Sorry if my english isn't completly right... i'm german and even in my native language writing isn't my strongest skill :D)

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
              select
                  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                  where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
                  select list[i];
}

public void PowerSetofcards()
{
    var result = GetPowerSet(cards);
    result.ToString().ToArray().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: So if you have more than 10 cards, you only want to use the first 10?

Comment: Well its likePokemon Cards. You got them all in a List and want to get all possible Combinations.
If I cut off the end i guess i would get doubled results or?

Comment: I've no idea how Pokemon works, just tell me what you want to happen if you have more than 10 cards.

Comment: I actually don't want to get more then ten cards

Comment: Then does my answer work?

Comment: So optimum would be that they wouldn't be listed

Comment: I cannot really tell what your goal is, and the code snippet seems to be missing some essential parts; so I can only give you some general advice: if you are not firm in c#, don't copy and try to adapt linq snippets, instead try to solve this with some simple [for loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx). I think two nested loops should suffice in your case, although again I am a little confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay guess should try that.

Well my Plan is that i got a list of names. And out of this list the Program should always take ten names. And this it should do for every possible combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make sure you only pass in the first 10 cards:

```
public void PowerSetofcards()
{
    var result = GetPowerSet<string>(cards.Count() > 10 ? cards.Take(10).ToList() : cards);
    result.ToString().ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I got this error code:

The type arguments of Elemental_Kingdoms.DIsettings.GetPowerSet <T> (System.Collections.Generic.List <T>) - Method can not be derived by inference from the syntax. Enter the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: OK, I've made an edit, but guessed at the type of card.

Comment: The list is List<String> cards = new List<String>(); So it should be <String> or? but now it tells me "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" can't be converted to "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>